# with sencha touch and phonegap how to post data to the remote server

Tags: android, cordova, post, sencha-touch-2

I aways use `jsonp` get data form the remote server to display.
And now I want to send a comments to remote server.
Because jsonp use http get to send, so the `comments length have limit`.
Then I change to use `post`, but got `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`
What should I do? I'm use sencha touch and phonegap to build android web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to whitelist the domain name you are attempting to access.

There is some guidance on the PhoneGap docs here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Obviously, check the correct version of this document for the version of PhoneGap you are using. I've given you the link for 2.7.0.

Comment: THX very much!~~ I wanted to try to make the phonegap plugin invoke the Java to send a post request. But your solution is more simple and practical.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in the header file where you receive the application data remotely

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```